# ScalaTest Scalactic - Custom Double Equality with tolerance including Double.NaN case

Tags: scala, nan, equality, scalatest, scalactic

I am trying to create a custom matcher that will take into account Double.NaN and will use tolerance for non-nan values.

```
import org.scalactic.{Equality, TolerantNumerics}
import org.scalatest.Matchers

trait MoreMatchers extends Matchers {

  implicit def doubleEqWithNaNAndTol: Equality[Double] = new Equality[Double] {

    implicit val tolerance: Equality[Double] = TolerantNumerics.tolerantDoubleEquality(1e-6)

    def areEqual(expected: Double, actual: Any): Boolean = actual match {
      case number: Double if number.isNaN => expected.isNaN
      case _: Double => actual === expected
      case _ => false
    }

  }
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work.

```
assert(0.00226685508536916 === 0.0022668550853691587)  // failure - doesn't use tolerance
assert (Double.NaN === Double.NaN )  // success
```

If enter the tolerance within the assertion then it fails if there are NaN.

```
assert(0.00226685508536916 === 0.0022668550853691587 +- 1e-6)  // success
assert (Double.NaN === Double.NaN  +- 1e-6)  // failure - can't use tolerance when NaN
```

If I just call it like the following, then it works.

```
implicit val tolerance: Equality[Double] = TolerantNumerics.tolerantDoubleEquality(1e-6)

def eq(expected: Double, actual: Double): Boolean = expected match {
    case x if x.isNaN => actual.isNaN
    case _ => actual === expected
}
```

And then call it as:

```
assert(eq(...,...))
```

I am wondering if it is possible to get it working using the first way. Have you come across such case before? Could you suggest any solutions? Any help will be appreciated :)

Thanks,
ele

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks to eirikr @d6 :), see solution in [custom equality gist](https://gist.github.com/non/291ef33197e4c7d17b7e437cd1c6e87d)

Basically in the above code you need to use `tolerance.areEqual(expected, number)` when comparing non-nan doubles in order to be able to use the tolerance implicit in that comparison.

```
import org.scalactic.{Equality, TolerantNumerics}
import org.scalatest.Matchers

trait MoreMatchers extends Matchers {

  implicit def doubleEqWithNaNAndTol: Equality[Double] = new Equality[Double] {

    implicit val tolerance: Equality[Double] = TolerantNumerics.tolerantDoubleEquality(1e-6)

    def areEqual(expected: Double, actual: Any): Boolean = actual match {
      case x: Double if x.isNaN => expected.isNaN
      case x: Double => tolerance.areEqual(expected, x)
      case _ => false
    }

  }
```

Regards,
ele